# Can't click hyperlinks in the \includepdf included pdfs

Tags: hyperref, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf)

I am having a problem getting `hyperref` links work in document that is assembled from other documents that have been `\includepdf` included.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem:

I have two documents - `doc.tex` and `otherdoc.tex`. `doc.tex` includes the `otherdoc.pdf`, which contains a `\href`. When the final document `doc.pdf` is produced, I can't click on the links in it.

doc.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document} 

\includepdf{otherdoc.pdf}

\end{document}
```

otherdoc.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\Large \href{http://twitter.com/pkrumins}{@pkrumins}

\end{document}
```

I can click the link in the `otherdoc.tex` but as soon as I compile `doc.tex`, which produces `doc.pdf`, I can no longer click links. Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Hyperlinks and other annotations in included PDFs are removed by pdfTeX. So this behavior is unfortunately normal. Have a look on [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf) for further information. This question could be taken as duplicate.

Comment: @Martin Would you consider making that an answer? As it is, the question is doomed to stay on the unanswered list.

Comment: @vanden: I closed it as a duplicate instead. After all `\includepdf` is just a special form of `\includegraphics`.