# How to include PDF as graphics and as attachment without using extra file space

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages, attachfile, file-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attach displayed image to the PDF without storing it twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/attach-displayed-image-to-the-pdf-without-storing-it-twice)

Is it at all possible to include a PDF as a graphic in the document and also as an internal attachment to the final document PDF *without* duplicating the internal data of the graphics in the resulting PDF?

Just to give an idea, the following code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
dummy text
\textattachfile[color=1 0 0, zoom=true, appearance=true]{pic.pdf}{
 \includegraphics{pic.pdf}
}
\end{document}
```

... does include the given pdf as a graphics and also as attachment, but the information is duplicated as it can be obviously found by inspecting the sizes of the final PDFs. To be specific with sizes, an essentially empty pdf produce a 20kB file. The with the code above the file is 80kB, but with the includegraphics commented *or* attachfile commented the size is ~30kB. So the data is obviously repeated in the final PDF. Is it possible to avoid this, either using some PDF trick or by enforcing compression of duplicated data?

(The reason is that I like this kind of feature for PDFs that include many many graphics, usually bigger than in the example but I don't want to pay double in final PDF size.)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Attach displayed image to the PDF without storing it twice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/attach-displayed-image-to-the-pdf-without-storing-it-twice). Unfortunately there is only a quit tricky solution for it yet. I hope that in the future someone finds a better one.