# Embedding a PDF file with clickable external links into a LaTeX document

Tags: pdf, links, embedding

I want to embed a screenshot of a web page into a LaTeX document as a vector graphic with
clickable links.

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to render the web page as a letter-sized pdf file with working links.  Then, I'm using this command to crop the pdf file while retaining the links:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "screenshot_cropped.pdf" -c "[/CropBox [`gs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE "screenshot.pdf" 2>&1 | awk '/HiRes/ { print $2,$3,$4,$5 }'`] /PAGES pdfmark" -f "screenshot.pdf"
```

(Commands taken from [this thread on comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/e1491c733c7e3e53); I can't use [pdfcrop](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop), since it apparently removes the links)

Finally, I'm embedding the file into my LaTeX document with the following:

```
\includegraphics[width=6 in]{screenshot_cropped.pdf}
```

Unfortunately, the links no longer work in the resulting pdf file.  How can I fix this?  I'm using XeLaTeX if it matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Quoting the [`pdfpages` manual (page 2)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page=2):

> [...] all kinds of links<sup>1</sup> will get lost during inclusion. (Using `\includepdf`,
>   `\includegraphics`, or other low-level commands.)
>
> However, there's a gleam of hope. Some links may be extracted and later
>   reinserted by a package called *pax* which can be downloaded from CTAN [[3]](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pax/).
>   Have a look at it!

The [`pax`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pax) package mentioned is actually a Java program which reads the PDF file, extracts the links and writes their positions to a `.pax` file. This information can be processed by an extended version of `\includegraphics` which reinserts the links at the correct position. However, the package is considered experimental *and only works with `pdfLaTeX`*.

This is how to use `pax`:

- Download and install [the package from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pax/pax-tds.zip).
- Run `pdfannotextractor.pl --install`. This downloads and installs [`PDFBox`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), a Java library necessary for using `pax`.
- Now you can run `pdfannotextractor.pl <filename.pdf>` in order to read the links from any given PDF file and write them to `filename.pax`.
- In your LaTeX document, invoke `\usepackage{pax}`. This extends `\includegraphics` in order to read and process the auxiliary `.pax` file.

Regarding the cropping of the PDF file with Ghostscript: In my experiments, this seemed to confuse `pax`, resulting in wrong positions of the hyperlinks. So it's probably best to call `wkhtmltopdf` with

```
wkhtmltopdf -B 0mm -L 0mm -R 0mm -T 0mm
```

in order to not create any margin from the start.

---

This is my working test case (using the site https://tex.stackexchange.com/about):

#### Creation of the PDF and the annotation file:

```
wkhtmltopdf -B 0mm -L 0mm -R 0mm -T 0mm https://tex.stackexchange.com/about screenshot.pdf
pdfannotextractor.pl screenshot.pdf
```

#### LaTeX source code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pax}

% Visible squares for demonstration purposes, can be removed without harm
% (change \iftrue to \iffalse or remove the following lines altogether)
\iftrue
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    filebordercolor={1 1 0},
  }
\fi

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{screenshot}
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: output result, with visible squares denoting hyperlinks]

<sub>*(The cyan boxes are there to prove that hyperlinks work, and can be removed without consequences.)*</sub>

Comment: I am using the `full` TeXLive installation in Fedora 19, when I try to run `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl [--install|file.pdf]` I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pdfbox/cos/ICOSVisitor`. (using `perl v5.16.3`). I tried this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79006/1871 but I still get an error (see in the comment to Heiko's answer there).

Comment: Hi @diabonas: I followed your method using pax, but it doesn't work in my example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243855/includepdf-seems-to-remove-internal-links-within-included-each-pdf-file. Am I missing something? For example, you can combine an arbitrary pdf, and a pdf generated from http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book9/mf1210.htm, which contains internal links.

Comment: If one encounters `Division by 0`, one has to patch `PAX@viewport` as described there https://gist.github.com/koppor/16659c4ef9ab7d088b2bc6eef420762e

Answer (score 9):

I'm worried this is not going to be possible.  It reminds me of a remark from the PGF manual regarding the `pgfpages` package.

> A word of warning: *using `pgfpages` will destroy hyperlinks*. Actually, the hyperlinks are not destroyed, only they will appear at totally wrong positions on the final output. This is due to a fundamental flaw in the pdf specification: In pdf the bounding rectangle of a hyperlink is given in “absolute page coordinates” and translations or rotations do not affect them. Thus, the transformations applied by pgfpages to put the pages where you want them are (cannot, even) be applied to the coordinates of hyperlinks. It is unlikely that this will change in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package [newpax](https://ctan.org/pkg/newpax). Unlike [diabonas' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44104/212801), this package works with LuaLaTeX and XeTeX.