# How to install PDFBox on Windows so it works with pax?

Tags: windows, pdfpages, pax

I am trying to use `pdfpages` and maintain the internal bookmarks within the included PDF files.  The [`pdfpages` README](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) suggests using the `pax` package for this purpose, so I have installed that from CTAN and refreshed my database (MiKTeX 2.9).

I am running **Windows 7 (64-bit)** and have installed JRE and JDK (in that order) and Strawberry Perl (to folder `C:\StrawberryPerl\`).

I downloaded PDFBox version 0.7.3 (which is supposed to be compatible with `pax`) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfbox/files/ and installed it to `C:\PDFBox`.

Then I added `C:\PDFBox\` and `C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\` to my system `Path` variable and rebooted.

Then I installed `pdfannotextractor.pl` using the command line:

```
perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --install
```

with the following result:

```
C:\>perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --install
PDFAnnotExtractor 0.1l, 2012/04/18 - Copyright (c) 2008, 2011, 2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
* Nothing to do, because PDFBox is already found:
  C:\PDFBox

C:\>
```

So `PDFBox` seems to be installed satisfactorily.  However, when I try to run the `pax` script using the following command:

```
java -jar C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pax.jar FileWithBookmarks.pdf
```

I get this result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pdfbox/cos/ICOSVisitor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pdfbox.cos.ICOSVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

If instead I use the following command:

```
perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl FileWithBookmarks.pdf
```

I get the same java exception as above.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**  After adding `C:\PDFBox\` to my CLASSPATH, here is my command and the debugging results:

```
C:\>perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --debug FileWithBookmarks.pdf
PDFAnnotExtractor 0.1l, 2012/04/18 - Copyright (c) 2008, 2011, 2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
* CLASSPATH: [.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\PDFBox\]
* is_win: [1]
* Which kpsewhich: [C:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\kpsewhich.EXE]
* Backticks: [kpsewhich --progname pdfannotextractor --format texmfscripts pax.jar]
* Exit code: [0/success]
* pax.jar: [C:/MiKTeX/scripts/pax/pax.jar]
* PDFBox in CLASSPATH: [yes]
* Which java: [C:\Windows\system32\java.EXE]
* System: [java -cp C:/MiKTeX/scripts/pax/pax.jar;C:\PDFBox;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\PDFBox\ pax.PDFAnnotExtractor FileWithBookmarks.pdf]
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-server       to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is server.

-cp 
-classpath 
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D=
              set a system property
-verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:...|:]
-enableassertions[:...|:]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:...|:]
-disableassertions[:...|:]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:[=]
              load native agent library , e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:[=]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:[=]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
* Exit code: [1]

C:\>
```

Comment: The error messages let me guess, that you need to change the classpath for `java` to (or add to it) at least one of the PDFBox jar files, which one, I don’t know now. A side note: There were no need for installing `pax` manually from CTAN, you could have used the MiKTeX Package Manager as well.

Comment: Please add option `--debug`, it does give more clues.

Comment: See `--debug` results above (I can't paste them here for some reason).

Comment: Brian, are the errors gone or not? The classpath in `java -cp C:/MiKTeX/scripts/pax/pax.jar;C:\PDFBox;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\PDFBox\ ...` looks dubious. I suppose the spaces caused the problems. (You see, that `C:\PDFBox\ ` was already added to the classpath by `pax`, I think, but probably not seen.) And: You need to attribute Heiko (or me) the way I did it in my comment below.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I just want to point you to Brian’s edit.

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same java error.  I uninstalled everything Java and reinstalled the JDK and JRE to paths without spaces; and then rebooted my computer.  After all that I'm still getting the same java error when I run `perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --debug FileWithBookmarks.pdf` (but the `java -cp` part no longer has the duplicate `C:\PDFBox\` references).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In addition to Heiko’s answer and just for convenience (Windows only):**

Create a file `pax.bat` (or `pax.cmd` or what ever you prefer instead of `pax`) under the `bin` subfolder of your local texmf tree. Under MiKTeX you perhaps first need to create one: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Now the preferred variant: **Executing the perl file** (an installation of a Perl distribution is necessary):

Edit `pax.bat`, adjust paths to your settings

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set CLASSPATH=C:\PDFBox\lib\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar;%CLASSPATH%

perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl %*
```

You could even leave out the `set CLASSPATH` line, if you’d create a path `<localtexmf>\scripts\pax\lib`, put `PDFBox-0.7.3.jar` in it and refresh the filename database (fndb).

Then on the Command Prompt you can call `pax FileWithBookmarks.pdf` or `pax --debug FileWithBookmarks.pdf > paxdebug.log`. This assumes, that there is no other `pax.exe` or similar on the system path, otherwise always make your call with `pax.bat ...`.

**Executing java directly** is a bit more complicated:

Again edit `pax.bat` and adjust paths to your settings

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set CLASSPATH=C:\PDFBox\lib\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar;C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pax.jar;%CLASSPATH%

java pax.PDFAnnotExtractor %*
```

Note that `pax.jar` was added to the classpath. I prefer to set the environment variable `CLASSPATH`, but the command line option `-classpath`, or short `-cp`, works as well, as shown by Heiko.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have an unpacked PDFBox in `C:\PDFBox`, the `CLASSPATH` is wrong. Instead of the directory, the `.jar` file is needed: `C:\PDFBox\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar`.

Neither `C:\PDFBox\` nor `C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\` need to be added to the system `Path` variable.

The spaces in the argument for `java`'s option `-cp` should not be a problem, because the Perl script uses the array form of function `system`. But it can be tested:

```
java -cp "C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pax.jar;C:\PDFBox\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar" pax.PDFAnnotExtractor FileWithBookmarks.pdf
```

**Remarks:**

- In Linux/Unix the path separator `:` is used instead of `;`.
- Project `pax` does not support newer versions of `PDFBox`. The supported versions are `0.7.2` and `0.7.3`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same java error when I use the Perl wrapper, but I can now successfully bypass the wrapper and execute the command @HeikoOberdiek provided above (with `lib` added in the path):  `java -cp "C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pax.jar;C:\PDFBox\lib\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar" pax.PDFAnnotExtractor FileWithBookmarks.pdf` -- which generates the expected `FileWithBookmarks.pax` file.  Thanks to @Speravir and @HeikoOberdiek for their helpful responses.

Comment: @alfC: I have updated the answer to add the requirement for special versions of `PDFBox` and cleaned up the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In this installation tutorial, we rely on [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), because it eases installation much.

### Preparation steps

To install chocolatey, open an cmd with administrative privileges and run:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

See https://chocolatey.org/install for details. Afterwards, follow these steps:

- Installl [Java Runtime Environment](https://java.com/de/download/) using `choco install jre8`. [chocolatey page](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jre8).
- Install unzip, wget, and curl using `choco install unzip wget curl`.
- Install perl using `choco install strawberryperl`. [chocolatey page](https://chocolatey.org/packages/StrawberryPerl).

### MiKTeX

- Install pax using the MiKTeX package manager to `C:\MiKTeX`.
- Execute `perl C:\MiKTeX\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --install` to enable downloading of a pdfbox version fitting for pax.
- Ignore the error regarding "MiKTeX Configuration Utility"
- Start "MiKTeX Settings"
- Click on "Refresh FNDB"
- Click on "Update Formats"
- Now, `pdfannotextractor.pl` is ready to go

### TeXlive

- Execute `mkdir "C:/Users/USERNAME/.texlive2018"`
- Execute `perl C:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --install`

If you did the first command wrong, you'll see something like the following:

```
> perl perl C:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\pax\pdfannotextractor.pl --install
PDFAnnotExtractor 0.1l, 2012/04/18 - Copyright (c) 2008, 2011, 2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
!!! Error: Cannot create directory `C:/Users/Oliver/.texlive2018/texmf-var'!
```

(Inspiration by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44104/9075)