# hyperref link to file at position

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lyx, external-files

I'm a newbie.  I've figured out how to set up a hyperlink link to a file (in my case, a PDF) on the hard drive.  But I would also like to change the starting position when this PDF opens up.  This PDF has no sections or anything like that.  I'd like to jump to a line in the PDF.  Anybody know of an easy way to do this?

Comment: Related: [`\href[page=10,pdfremotestartview=FitV]` seems not to work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129941/5764), [How to create a link in a PDF document to open a file using a specified application installed on the machine?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6376/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\href\[page=10,pdfremotestartview=FitV\] seems not to work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129941/hrefpage-10-pdfremotestartview-fitv-seems-not-to-work)