# \hyperref and glossary integration with \includepdf / Microsoft Word?

Tags: pdf, glossaries, pdfpages, msword, word-to-latex

I have a compilation LaTeX document which has a number of `\includepdf`, as well as a number of `\input`ted `.tex` files, often linking into a glossary/acronym-list with `glossaries-extra`.

The PDFs that are being included are exported from Microsoft Word, and have internal references and bibliography's (commonly added with Zotero).

What's the best way of updating the LaTeX glossary to include hyperlinked references to pages number that acronym appears on, whether they are in `.tex` or come from Word (e.g.: in `.pdf`)?

E.g., is converting the docx to LaTeX then updating the LaTeX with `\GLS` a good/only way?

Comment: Some kind of MWE (github repo with examples maybe) would be of help, i think.
Did you try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44104  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79082 (with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87558) or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33915 ?

Comment: Your suggestion pointed out https://ctan.org/pkg/pax; I also found https://ctan.org/pkg/hypgotoe. There's a bit of indirection, but I think `hypgotoe` could work…