# \includepdf seems to remove internal links within included each PDF file?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfpages

`\includepdf` seems remove internal links within included each PDF file. For example, in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`2.pdf` has some internal links in some pages that, when clicked, will jump to some other pages.
after compiling the above latex code by `pdflatex`, the output pdf lose the internal links.

I followed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44104/861 using pax, but it doesn't seem to make the internal links work in my example. Am I missing something? For example, you can combine an arbitrary pdf, and a pdf generated from [this webpage](http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book9/mf1210.htm) which contains internal links.

Comment: None of the replies in the linked post can solve my questions.

Comment: Another solution based on `onimage.sty`, `pdftk` and `Perl` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423471

Comment: @Tim: Citing one of the linked answers "You can not simply mix two PDF files. You have to preserve PDF document structure. In the simply case links (PDF annotations) are dropped.". Sorry, it will not work. If you need to combine two PDFs while preserving hyperlinks don't use LaTeX but a dedicated PDF tool like Adobe Acrobat (no, not the Reader, the full program, which costs a lot unfortunately) or some of the cheaper alternatives.