# Error installing PDFBox library for pax package

Tags: packages, java, perl, pax

On Ubuntu 14.04, I followed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44104/861.

First install `pax` package.

```
$ sudo tlmgr install pax
```

Then run `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install`. Note I have to specify the perl script's full path, because it isn't found otherwise. This downloads and installs `PDFBox`, a Java library necessary for using `pax`. But I had this error "Installation failed, because PDFBox library cannot be found!".

```
$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install

...
* Downloaded: $TEXMFVAR/scripts/pax/PDFBox-0.7.3.zip
Archive:  $TEXMFVAR/scripts/pax/PDFBox-0.7.3.zip
  inflating: $TEXMFVAR/scripts/pax/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar  
* Unpacked: $TEXMFVAR/scripts/pax/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar
texhash: Updating /tmp/$TEXMFVAR/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
!!! Error: Installation failed, because PDFBox library cannot be found!
```

The perl script also creates a directory `$TEXMFVAR` under my current dir with following content:

```
$ ls \$TEXMFVAR/*
$TEXMFVAR/ls-R

$TEXMFVAR/scripts:
pax
```

and the pdfbox library is installed as `\$TEXMFVAR/scripts/pax/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar`, although not found.

`TEXMFVAR` is used in the script [`pdfannotextractor.pl`](http://ctan.mackichan.com/graphics/metapost/base/source/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl). 
I guess the perl script doesn't find the proper value of `TEXMFVAR`, and `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var` may be the right value? Then I want to pass this value to `pdfannotextractor.pl` by

```
$ TEXMFVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var sudo -E /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install

...
* Downloaded: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/scripts/pax/PDFBox-0.7.3.zip
Archive:  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/scripts/pax/PDFBox-0.7.3.zip
  inflating: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/scripts/pax/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar  
* Unpacked: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/scripts/pax/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
!!! Error: Installation failed, because PDFBox library cannot be found!
```

Now it is installed to the intended directory as `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/scripts/pax/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar`, but still can't be found.

Thanks.

Comment: I somehow have the feeling that this question would be better suited at AskUbuntu. You are mentioning the path business, is it possible that this is the cause and logging off/in might be the whole trick?

Comment: I can't log off now.