# Keep the functionality of the sidebar using \includepdf

Tags: beamer, pdfpages

I would like to include a second beamer presentation for supplementary material (SM) into the main file. I use the `\includepdf` command from the `pdfpages` package but I lost the functionality of the sections in the sidebar. How can I keep it?

Here's my code:

main file:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\section{a}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{a}
something...
\end{frame}

\section{b}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{b}
something...
\end{frame}

\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\includepdf[pages=-]{SM}
}

\end{document}
```

SM file:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\begin{document}

\section{sm 1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{supplementary material 1}
supplementary material...
\end{frame}

\section{sm 2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{supplementary material 2}
supplementary material...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have the source code for both presentations, why not simply insert the old presentation into your new one?

Comment: I guess the problem is the usage of different themes then. And for the use of `pdfpages` directly, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf. The underlying problem might be the same.

Comment: You are including whole pages with `\includepdf`. The format and layout of the pages in the current document has no effect, basically. You can overlay stuff, if necessary e.g. to add a header or footer in a regular document. But this is not going to work well in something like Beamer, I don't think. Why not use `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Do you mean you lost the functionality of stuff from the included pages? That's inevitable because inclusion breaks hyperlinks. The documentation suggests that some functionality can be 'put back' with post-processing, though I've never tried that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pax` package works fine also using different themes. See also: [Embedding a PDF file with clickable external links into a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/embedding-a-pdf-file-with-clickable-external-links-into-a-latex-document/44104#44104)

Cheers

Comment: That's the bit in the documentation I was thinking of in my comment.

Comment: Indeed you make the file `.pax` to have the functionality back