# No hyperref funktion in externalized TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, externalize

I'm a bit confused as I read the TikZ manual.
Is there a opportunity to `hyperref` out of an externalized TikZ graphic into the main document?

When I compile the following code with `pdflatex` and `--shell-escape` and then do a make command and then again `pdflatex`, I get a main document without the hyperlink in the graph.

[image]

But when I compile it without externalize it works well.

[image]

Is there a solution for this Problem?

It would be great :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {root}
    child {node {\ref{eq:einstein}left}}
    child {node {right}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

Gleichung Nr.\ref{eq:einstein}.
\newpage
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:einstein}
 E = m \cdot c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So doesn't anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Well, with current MiKTeX I can compile your given code without errors but one warning that one image is not up to date and schould be generated. But I can see the hyperlink to the equation:

[image]

Comment: If you do the make command the image will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out, that it is only possible to get the label number.
But there is no possibility to get the hyperlink when you do the externalization.
This is technically not possible.

It is written here in german:
https://golatex.de/keine-hyperref-funktion-in-externer-tikz-grafik-t21388.html

So I changed to LuaLaTeX and do it all at once without externalization.
It works fine, but takes reaaally long to compile.

There was an idea to recover the links with pax:
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44104/2388
But I couldn't make it...

So if anyone can achive this, just add an answer please...

Comment: Indeed hypertargets to sub-PDFs are lost on inclusion, which is a technical limitation. I would just bite the sour apple and compile it in full once your document is final. I had such a thing on my PhD thesis and didn't minded to wait 10min for the final PDF as long I get a nearly correct review version within 30s using externalization technics (However, I used `standalone` for that, well actually I wrote `standalone` for just that).