# Maintain the link in .pdf file included in latex with command \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I need to insert a pdf file in latex and I use the \includepdf command and it work fine.
However the link present in the pdf will be lost when it was uploaded in latex with the above command. 
Can you please help me? Are there an option to avoid this situation?

thank you,

LC

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/embedding-a-pdf-file-with-clickable-external-links-into-a-latex-document/44104#44104), does it provide a solution for your problem?

Comment: With lualatex it is possible with a bit luacode. With pdftex you need pax (which isn't easy to use).