# Import pdf form in latex with filled in text

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, includegraphics

For a thesis I have to add a university specific title page and a declaration of originality to my LaTeX document.

Both are pdf forms. So I can fill in the gaps directly in the pdf and also save it. However, after compiling with `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf` the filled in gaps are not considered and blank in the pdf output.

Is there a possibility to avoid this problem?

I also tried to save it in different pdf formats as pdf/A, pdf/E, pdf/X. My last act will be print and scan.

Comment: I don't know if there is a proper LaTeX way, but you could just print to pdf and include the resulting file. (Should be without loss of quality.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since I have not found a direct solution yet, this is by far the easiest way!

Comment: such form fields are basically annotations, and annotations are not imported. To flatten the pdf by printing it to a pdf is the easiest and sensible solution.

Comment: @schtandard -- Please post an answer so this won't be lost.

Comment: Similar question, but for annotation: [graphics - Modifications on PDF file do not show up - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33413/modifications-on-pdf-file-do-not-show-up?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, just like annotations, form fields in PDF files are not imported. The easiest way to include a filled out version of the form is to print it to PDF and include the resulting file.