# Adding a cover image to an existing pdf file breaks th links of the original pdf

Tags: hyperref, pdf, pdfpages, links, embedding

We have a main.pdf, and a cover image and a tex file. When we use texlive2013 to add the cover image and the contents of the tex file in the main pdf, the links in the main pdf breaks, in the sense the texts that were links are still coming in blue but they are not pointing to anything anymore, they are just normal texts.

Contents of the tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times,color,graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{covergray}{gray}{0.5}
\usepackage[pdftex,%
  pdfstartview=FitH,%
  bookmarks=false,%
  colorlinks=true,%
  urlcolor=covergray%
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\parindent=0pt\parskip=0.5pc

\begin{center}\bf
\vfill
\begin{center}
  \frame{\includegraphics[height=1.0\hsize]{cover.jpg}}
\end{center}
\vfill
\color{covergray}
Some text
\href{http://www.google.com}{http://www.google.com}
\end{center}
\includepdf[pages=-]{main.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is well known, I'm not sure if there is any solution to this other than including the cover in the original file in the first place. I saw an explanation about this at some point but don't remember it.

Comment: @daleif: [This one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14632/5763)?

Comment: @MartinSchröder, not really it was explaining why hyperrefs got lost. I don't understand much os the inner workings of PDF anyway.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK all TeX drivers that can include PDF images strip the annotations from the pages including links.

Workarounds:

- If `main.pdf` was generated via TeX, then the best strategy would be to add the cover page there to keep the links and outlines in `main.pdf`.
- There is a project [`pax` (PdfAnnotExtractor)](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax) that uses the Java library `PDFBox` (in an older version) to extract some annotations and a LaTeX package hooks into `\includegraphics` (used by `pdfpages`) to insert them afterwards.
- [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can keep some annotations:

  ```
  pdftk cover.pdf main.pdf cat output new.pdf
  ```

  but the outlines of `main.pdf` are lost.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but what is `outlines` in this context?

Comment: @daleif: Bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Will try to use pdftk and see if it works.