# Include PDF with OCGs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf, ocg

I want to avoid to recompile large tikz graphics and therefore I compile them as a standalone pdf file. This file contains some OCG layers which I want to use in the main file, but the OCG layer are ignored in the main file.

OCG file (ocg-pdf.pdf):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ocgx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Layer1,ref=l1,status=visible}]
                \filldraw[color=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Layer2,ref=l2,status=visible}]
                \filldraw[color=blue] (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{ocg-pdf}
\end{document}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This may have nothing to do with TikZ at all. Does a generalized PDF with OCGs retain its "OCG-ness" when included using `\includegraphics`? (Sorry, I have no time to test myself at the moment.)

Comment: Right in general this does not work with includegraphics. I have tested this for example with (http://acroeng.adobe.com/Test_Files/OCG//CADSample.pdf)

Comment: May not be technicaly related but it reminds me of this limitation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf

Answer (score 10):

There is currently no way to do this with standard pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX, as there is no way to wire the OCGs in the included PDFs with the OCGs in the including document (this *may* be doable with the new PDF library in LuaTeX, though - but nobody has done that yet).

I solved this some years ago in a version of pdfTeX available [here](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/branches/qstex/?root=pdftex); there is some documentation on this [here](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/branches/qstex/doc/optionalcontent.pdf?revision=719&root=pdftex).

That version is not maintained anymore and the work has not been incorporated into any stable engine, though.

Comment: Is this a pdfTeX/LuaTeX limitation or essentially a PDF one?

Comment: @JosephWright: It's a problem of the engines (and not well designed in PDF) - it's more difficult than "just" including a PDF page.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: is it possible that your solution could somehow be merged into the official branch of TeX?

Comment: @MartinHeller: I think patches for LuaTeX would be welcomed. I'm not involved with pdfTeX anymore.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: please consider submitting the patch to LuaTeX. I think the OP is not the only one who would like to see this feature included.