# Is there a possibility to include a pdf with defined layers?

Tags: pdfpages, ocg

I can insert pdf pages with the `pdfpages`. There are options to select pages ...

But I found nothing to select specific layers.
Is there a possibility?

### Details

#### PDF to be included

The following code creates a document with layers:

```
\documentclass[english,ngerman,latin]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{ocgx2} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Main}
\blindtext

%Parameter: {ocg}{name}{id}{visibility}
\begin{ocg}{German}{german}{1}
\section{German}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}\blindtext
\end{ocg}

\begin{ocg}{English}{english}{1}
\section{English}
\selectlanguage{english}\blindtext
\end{ocg}

\section{Main - continue}
\ldots
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

In the viewer I can select, if I see the German/English layer.

### File with pdfpages

Now I want to include my test document in another pdf.
It works with `\includepdf{test_ocg_article}` but I found no possibility to include it with invisible German text.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}
\includepdf{test_ocg_article}%Works fine, everything is shown

%Option to exclude a layer does not exist:
% \includepdf[layer=german]{test_ocg_article}
% \includepdf[invisible=german]{test_ocg_article}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- The pdf I want to include is not created with LaTeX. I'm looking for a solution for any pdf with layers.
- I don't expect to get the layers in my main document.
  See [Include PDF with OCGs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209299/include-pdf-with-ocgs) for this topic.
- I want to include the pdf multiple times. Everytimes with different layer visibilies. So it does not help, to set selected layers as invisible (I would need a pdf-file for each variant of layer settings).

Comment: can you please explain your final goal? if I understand you want to have 2 documents one without english section and second without german section? no?

Comment: @touhami I want to have one document. This document contains the pdf with layers multiple times, each time with different layers. (It's a kind of explanation: 'You can take document X and activate the layers 1,2,... and inactivate layer 8 and 9. Then you can see (figure XY)....'). Actually I have to make a screenshot of each figure I want. And If I understand AlexG correct, that's the only possibility.

Comment: @AlexG That's what I suspected, but I wanted to be sure. Can you make an answer of your comment - so I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: @knut exactly, but rather than  screenshot one can try a trick like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301189/comments-tips-on-a-non-latex-pdf-including-mathematical-formulas/301599#301599)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial visibility of layers is hard-wired in the `/Catalog` of the PDF file. None of the known drivers (pdfTeX, `dvips`, `dvipdfmx`, XeTeX) provide a means to override these settings upon file inclusion. Thus, it is (most likely) not possible.

Comment: I am not sure whether LuaTeX allows for low level PDF operations of such kind.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the current systems (although this *may* be possible with some Lua code in LuaTeX). There is an unmaintained fork of pdftex (made by me) at the [pdftex repository](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/branches/qstex/?root=pdftex) that *is* able to do this (with some additional primitives).

Comment: Sounds promising! Lat's see, if it finds it way to the official release.

Comment: @knut: Unlikely as nobody is working on it.