# Preserve hyperlinks in included PDF in LyX?

Tags: lyx, pdf, links

It seems that in LaTeX, it is not generally possible to preserve the hyperlinks in an included PDF (see e.g. "[How to preserve hyperlinks in included PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/)").

However, I was wondering: Does this feature exist for LyX specifically?

---

And if not, how difficult would it be to implement it? (I should like to submit a request for such a feature.)

In Adobe Acrobat it is a very simple matter to insert PDF with hyperlinks preserved, so I am not sure why this is difficult/impossible to do in LaTeX or LyX.

Comment: Since LyX simply constructs a LaTeX file and uses LaTeX to compile it, there is no different behaviour in LyX. This can't really be a feature request for LyX either. It has to be supported in the LaTeX graphics include packages (`graphicx` and `pdfpages`). My guess is that it isn't so easy to do since otherwise someone would have done it...

Comment: One of the reasons you give away software such as a reader for your own format is so you can charge for the editor so Acrobat charges for supporting this ability, however there are many free applications that can do one simple task such as insert hyperlinks to known positions just beware of the "Honest Johns" you meet on the way to the market.

Comment: With luatex it should be possible to extract the annotations and to reinsert them like the old pax package does it, but imho nobody yet has written the needed code - unless context has some.