# How to keep a link with underscore stable when inserting the pdf?

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages, underscore

I'm setting up my job application portfolio, and want to link my email address. However, when I insert the pdf with the linked email address to my portfolio, the link does not work properly anymore.

It works just fine without an underscore.

1. Creating document "email"

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \begin{document}
   \href{mailto:fnm_lnm@abc.org}{fnm\_lnm@abc.org}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Inserting the pdf

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf{email}
   \end{document}
   ```

I expect the hyperlink to be `fnm_lnm@abc.org`, but instead it reads `lnm@abc.org`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you talking about the typeset appearance of the e-mail or about the hyperlink?

Comment: I'm referring to the hyperlink.

Comment: For me no hyperlink is generated whatsoever. According to this thread there is a "pax" project: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14620/134574 I tried to make it work but failed.

Comment: Strange that no hyperlink at all is generated for you. In the documentation of the pdfpages package it says that it is unable to copy links. I also came across the pax project, but didn't work for me neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get no link in the included pdf (as the package documents) neither xpdf nor windows 
firefox detect any link.

acrobat does make a bad link starting from after the `_` but (I think) that is just "guessing" a link and inferring it from the text.  If you use OT1 then `\_` is constructed as a rule not a character, so if the pdf reader is guessing email addresses of the form `<letters and dots>@<letters and dots>` then it will not include the prefix. However with T1 encoding `\_`  does resolve to a character in the font and so the heuristic gets lucky.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I still get the same result. Don't know why. I'm working with TeXstudio compiling with PdfLaTeX using MiKTex. Any ideas why results could differ?

Comment: @U.Manhold as I say,  not working is the expected outcome. There is no link in the pdf so most viewers I tried the issue does not arise at all. Only acrobat of the viewers I tried try to guess a link from the text here and guesses wrong if you use the default OT1 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in line 3 of `email.tex` eliminates the problem. Admittedly, I don't really understand why. The link in the second pdf (generated from the file that includes `email.pdf`) isn't highlighted, but it does work.